# Problems with image size in splash screen in android project

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have done a splash screen in my android project, and I have used an image. The problem is that the image fills all the screen and it is seen cut, as the image shows[splash screen cut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x77aa.png)

Here are my files:
Splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/primary_color"/>


    <item

        android:gravity="center"

        android:drawable="@drawable/cabeza_robot"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>


</layer-list>
```

I have tried changing layout_height and width attributes but it doesn´t work.
And here is the image
[image for splash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhcuC.png)

Thank you.

EDIT:
the solution is using `android:height` instead of `android:layout_height`

Comment: Add the splash_screen layout xml code.

Comment: Have you tried using **android:height** and not **android:layout_height** ?

Comment: @gioravered Thank you very much. That is the solution. I will update my question so anyone can see the answer.

Comment: @gioravered I tried your solution but then it showed erroe with the webview kit, saying missing attribute. can you help please